# How to access elements in a ListView when long clicked

Tags: java, android, android-listview, contextmenu

I am working on an application that has a `ListView` of movies. The list is declared as an array in `strings.xml`. It has elements, `Title`, `Gross` and `Date Released`. When a row is long clicked, it brings up a context menu that allows the user to edit said row or delete it. When the user picks Edit, he/she is brought to a 2nd screen with 3 Edit Text corresponding to `Title`, `Gross` and `Date`. The `EditText` fields are initialized with the data from the clicked row. Here is my code:

```
     @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    String[] titleList = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.title_array);
    String[] grossList = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.gross_array);
    String[] dateList = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.date_array);

    results = new ArrayList<Lab8_082588FetchDetails>();

    for (int i = 0; i < titleList.length; i++) {
        Lab8_082588FetchDetails sr = new Lab8_082588FetchDetails();
        sr.setTitle(titleList[i]);
        sr.setGross(grossList[i]);
        sr.setDate(dateList[i]);
        results.add(sr);
    }

    adapter = new SampleCustomAdapter(results);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

    ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
            registerForContextMenu(lv);


      }
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();

    // places the contents of the XML to the menu
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.context_menu, menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item
            .getMenuInfo();
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.delete:
        results.remove(info.position);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        return true;
    case R.id.edit:
        System.out.println(info.id);
        System.out.println(info.position);

        Intent newData = new Intent(Lab8_082588.this, Lab8_082588Edit.class);
        results.get(info.position);
        TextView movieTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
        TextView movieGross = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.gross);
        TextView movieDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date);

        String startTitle = movieTitle.getText().toString();
        String startGross = movieGross.getText().toString();
        String startDate = movieDate.getText().toString();

        newData.putExtra(Lab8_082588Edit.TITLE_STRING, startTitle);
        newData.putExtra(Lab8_082588Edit.GROSS_STRING, startGross);
        newData.putExtra(Lab8_082588Edit.DATE_STRING, startDate);
        startActivityForResult(newData, Lab8_082588.EDIT_MOVIE);
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onContextItemSelected(item);

    }
}
```

For the Edit screen:

```
    public class Lab8_082588Edit extends Activity {

public static final String TITLE_STRING = "TITLE_STRING";
public static final String GROSS_STRING = "GROSS_STRING";
public static final String DATE_STRING = "DATE_STRING";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.addedit);
    initialize();
}

private void initialize() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Intent prepopulate = getIntent();
    EditText movieTitle = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etTitle);
    EditText movieGross = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etGross);
    EditText movieDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etDate);

    String startTitle = prepopulate.getStringExtra(Lab8_082588Edit.TITLE_STRING);
    String startGross = prepopulate.getStringExtra(Lab8_082588Edit.GROSS_STRING);
    String startDate = prepopulate.getStringExtra(Lab8_082588Edit.DATE_STRING);

    movieTitle.setText(startTitle);
    movieGross.setText(startGross.replaceAll(",", "").replace("$", ""));
    movieDate.setText(startDate);
}
```

My FetchDetails class

```
    public class Lab8_082588FetchDetails implements Comparable<Lab8_082588FetchDetails> {

private String title;
private String gross;
private String date;

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getGross() {
    return gross;
}

public void setGross(String gross) {
    this.gross = gross;
}

public String getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Lab8_082588FetchDetails another) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return title.compareTo(another.title);
}

 }
```

My Adapter:

```
  private class SampleCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    public SampleCustomAdapter(ArrayList<Lab8_082588FetchDetails> movies) {
        internalList = movies;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return internalList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int index) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return internalList.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View view;

        if (convertView == null) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
        } else {
            view = convertView;
        }

        // extract the views to be populated
        TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        TextView gross = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.gross);
        TextView date = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.date);

        // extract the object that will fill these
        Lab8_082588FetchDetails movie = internalList.get(position);

        title.setText(movie.getTitle());
        date.setText(movie.getDate());
        gross.setText(movie.getGross());

        // return the view
        return view;
    }
}
```

My problem is that, indeed, the Edit Texts get populated, but only with the data from the first item in the entire list (e.g. Titanic is first on the list, and is the only one being populated). Even if I click the nth row movie in the listview, Titanic is still the one being retrieved. How do I solve this?

Edit: I realize that somehow, the code is only considering the first element of the list. How do I access the elements of the other rows?

Comment: for long click you have to set setOnItemLongClickListener for listview

Comment: Updated my code. Just realized that ContextMenu is automatically Long Click in nature, so I removed the listener. My only concern is that I want to access the elements of the individual rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I realize that somehow, the code is only considering the first
>   element of the list. How do I access the elements of the other rows?

You should never do a search with `findViewById` for items which are in a `ListView` row. In the `onContextItemSelected` callback you have the position of the element clicked so you could use it to get the data associated with this row:

```
case R.id.edit:
    Intent newData = new Intent(Lab8_082588.this, Lab8_082588Edit.class);
    // I hope you implemented the adapter correctly
    Lab8_082588FetchDetails item = (Lab8_082588FetchDetails) getListView().getItemAtPosition(info.position); 
    String startTitle = item.getTitle();
    String startGross = item.getGross();
    String startDate = item.getDate();

    newData.putExtra(Lab8_082588Edit.TITLE_STRING, startTitle);
    newData.putExtra(Lab8_082588Edit.GROSS_STRING, startGross);
    newData.putExtra(Lab8_082588Edit.DATE_STRING, startDate);
    startActivityForResult(newData, Lab8_082588.EDIT_MOVIE);
    return true;
```

Comment: Updated my code. I'm having a type mismatch error with Lab8_082588FetchDetails item = getListView().getItemAtPosition(info.position); Im pretty sure I setup my adapter correctly.

Comment: @Erasmus Yes, I forgot the `getItemAtPosition` returns an `Object`. Cast the return to a `Lab8_082588FetchDetails` type. See my edited answer. Also make the `getItem` method of the adapter  to return a `Lab8_082588FetchDetails` instead of `Object`.

Comment: It worked wonderfully sir Luksprog! To be honest, I was quite lost about accessing individual ListViews. The professor never quite made it clear about findViewById when accessing individual elements.